# TypeError: '<' in putting items into priority queue

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am doing a task in which I have to make a priority queue containing entries in terms of a tuple and sorted according to start position or probability.
I have a class for putting entry to the queue in a proper order.
When I try to input into the queue it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Entry' and 'Entry'
```

Here is my code:

```
class Entry:
    #Entry to be used

    def __init__(self, word, start_pos, log_prob, back_ptr):
        self.word=word
        self.start_pos=start_pos
        self.log_prob=log_probability
        self.back_ptr=back_ptr
```

My code for entering item to the priority queue:

```
keys= Pw.keys()
pq  = PriorityQueue()
input=""
count=0


with open("data/input/dev.txt") as f:

    #getting the input ready, ommitting newline, joining together
    for line in f:
        n_line = line.strip()
        input=n_line
        finalindex=len(input)-1
        chart = [None] * (finalindex+1)

        #initializing priorityqueue, gather candidates for first word
        inserted=0
        for allowed_length in range(1,14):
            first_word=input[0:allowed_length]
            if first_word in Pw:
                #Pw is word probability
                entry=Entry(first_word,0,log10(Pw(first_word)),None)
                #print(entry)
                pq.put((0,entry))
                inserted+=1

            if inserted==0:
            first_word=input[0]
            entry = Entry(first_word,0,log10(Pw(first_word)), None)
            pq.put((0,entry))
```

I am getting an error in pq.put  of for loop.
I can sort queue to start_pos or log_prob.

I tried this in `class Entry`:

```
def _lt_ (self, other):
    return self.start_pos<other.start_pos
```

It didn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Error Adding Node() to Priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058482/python-error-adding-node-to-priority-queue)

Comment: I tried doing that by using a counter in the tuple and incrementing it, but, it didn't work!!

Comment: Your `def _lt_(self, other)` should be `def __lt__(self, other)`.

Comment: Hi, yeah I missed the one "_" which caused the error to come up!! Thanks!